# How to tag question that ask us to find a bug?

Tags: discussion, tags, source-code, homework

For example, [Javascript auto calculating with (+) and (-)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573480/javascript-auto-calculating-with-and)

I tagged it with [findbugs](/questions/tagged/findbugs) (I know what findbugs is, but I could not find anything better). I think it deserves to have its own category -- this way beginners can learn from each other and people that want to read complicated code can easy find it (this code is not that complicated, but I bet that it will evolve in future questions).

I've also tagged it [homework](/questions/tagged/homework), but it just doesn't feel right.

**EDIT:**

[Perfect example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573538/need-some-help-on-how-to-replay-the-last-game-of-a-java-maze-game), maybe [complex-code](/questions/tagged/complex-code) tag? I also removed that tag from the first question, it looked stupid.

**EDIT:**

What I dont like about the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag is that it is also used for questions that used to have the tag [show-me-teh-code](/questions/tagged/show-me-teh-code) (or something like that) when people want us to write some code for them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think it could be any of the following:

- `find-a-bug`
- `find-the-bug` ([reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321223918))
- `find-an-error`

Comment: nice idea with reference :)

Answer (score 12):

Please *don't* tag such questions with a special tag. Many questions are about finding bugs—it's not necessary to separate such questions.

> I think it deserves to have it own's category - this way beginners can learn from each other and people that want to learn how to read complicated code can easy find it(this code is not that complicated, but I bet that it will evolve in future questions).

The thing is, beginners probably won't learn from these questions—specific bugs are usually unique—it is highly unlikely that someone will have an identical bug.

Also, please don't tag questions [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) unless you are asking the question or it's specifically mentioned in the question—you don't know for sure if the question is homework, a challenge problem the OP has given him/herself, or even a legitimate production problem. This is Stack Overflow policy—see the 6th bullet point under "Answering Homework Questions" at the [Homework FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Finally, I noticed you tagged the question [code-sample](/questions/tagged/code-sample), presumably because there was code in the question. However, the question is not about code samples, it merely has code samples. [Stack Exchange policy officially discourages such meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

---

In response to your comments:

> so how should I tag them? for me its homework(they post the whole code and not just the sample that demonstrates the problem, because they just want it fix and really dont care how). I think you people are misusing the code-sample tag, for me that tag represent questions with complex code, but I will stop using it.

Don't tag them. Yes, it's considered a bit rude not to isolate the buggy code, but that's not the purpose of tagging. If a user wants to put the effort into reading a wall of code, that's fine, but most people will simply ignore it.

> Some people might enjoy fixing other people code(or maybe they want to practice,because they are looking for a new job?). Why you want to make it hard for them to find those kind of questions? I believe all homework questions should be closed, but if some people want to ... sell themselfs(however most of the time they wont even get accepted answer :D) for points than we should let them.

We're not making it hard to find these questions. See that *Unanswered* tab at the top of the page? It lists all the unanswered questions—those which people who enjoy answering questions should answer.

> also how to find "homework" questions without the tag? At job interviews we will see some really badly written code and we get asked stupid questions about how it works. "Practice makes perfect" and you might not have a choice - bad job or jobless. P.S. I think it many threads and thats why so many comments(and we all know editing comment is a crime).

You can use the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag; just don't tag *other peoples' questions* with [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) unless you're 100% sure it's real, legitimate homework assigned by a teacher in an actual academic course.

> p.s. thx for links, i will now just vote to close them "Admit that the question is homework. Trying to hide it will just get the question closed faster."

No, homework questions are perfectly acceptable. Please read the post I linked to in great detail.

> p.s. you were wrong - meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/73684/…, people think I use code-sample the right way.

No, people downvoted you because you should take responsibility and fix your own errors. Trust me, the Stack Exchange team has taken a great effort to eradicate these meta tags by deleting and banning them.

Comment: so how should I tag them? for me its homework(they post the whole code and not just the sample that demonstrates the problem, because they just want it fix and really dont care how). I think you people are misusing the code-sample tag, for me that tag represent questions with complex code, but I will stop using it.

Comment: Some people might enjoy fixing other people code(or maybe they want to practice,because they are looking for a new job?). Why you want to make it hard for them to find those kind of questions? I believe all homework questions should be closed, but if some people want to ... sell themselfs(however most of the time they wont even get accepted answer :D) for points than we should let them.

Comment: also how to find "homework" questions without the tag? At job interviews we will see some really badly written code and we get asked stupid questions about how it works. "Practice makes perfect" and you might not have a choice - bad job or jobless. P.S. I think it many threads and thats why so many comments(and we all know editing comment is a crime).

Comment: p.s. thx for links, i will now just vote to close them "Admit that the question is homework. Trying to hide it will just get the question closed faster."

Comment: p.s. you were wrong - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73684/please-remove-tag-code-sample-from-my-edits, people think I use code-sample the right way.

Comment: @01: *"people think I use code-sample the right way"* how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: they down voted my request to re-tag those questions, so they agree with me.

Comment: @01: Of course they don't. I have faith that you know you were voted down because you were acting petulant.

Comment: @01 I've replied to your comments. Please read the FAQ posts about homework questions and the meta tags blog post carefully, as they answer the last three questions you asked.