# Burninate the [findbugs] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [findbugs](/questions/tagged/findbugs) tag was created a year ago in a misguided attempt to ["tag questions that ask us to find a bug"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73648/how-to-tag-question-that-ask-us-to-find-a-bug).

It's a pure meta tag and should not exist.  The questions are not related and it can not stand alone.

There are about 200 questions with the tag right now, which is *way* above my threshold for stealth retagging.  Unless there is opposition, and unless someone gets to it before I do, I'm going to get this party started tomorrow.

Comment: Many of the questions relate to [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/). How else would one tag them?

Comment: Derp, I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taking a quick poke through the questions it seems that the majority of questions actually relate to [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), as mentioned by Shawn Chin. That's also what the tags summary mentions: [findbugs](/questions/tagged/findbugs).

Therefore it's not a meta-tag, but a concrete tool-related tag.

If it's used anywhere to actually mean "find my bugs", then *that's* an error.

Answer (score 9):

Many of the questions seem to be referring to [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/).

IMHO, the tag is legit and we just need to clean up (or close) questions that misuse it to request a bug search. SO is not a crowdsource debugger.